# qunit test that styles get applied to target elements

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, testing, qunit

I'm doing my first set of javascript unit tests against a plugin I'm writing.
It's based on a jquery ui widget and looks like this

```
$.widget("my.carousel", {
 // Set up the widget
        _create: function () {
            var self = this;
            _items = $(this.element).children();
            _totalItems = _items.length;
            _items.each(function(index) {
                $(this).addClass('my-carousel-item');
                if (index > 0) {
                    $(this).effect("scale", { percent: 50 });
                }
            });
}
```

So when it gets applied to an element it gets all of it's children and scales them to 50% apart from the first.

In my qunit tests I have

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    test('my-carousel-items are scaled to a given percentage if they are not the current item', function () {
            //setup
            var list = $('<div id="testDiv" />');
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                $('<div style="height:40px; background-color:red; margin-bottom:5px;">').appendTo(list);
            }
            $('#testArea').append(list);

            var carousel = list.carousel();

            expect(5);
            carousel.children().each(function(index) {
                if (index == 0)
                    equals($(this).css('height'), 40);
                else
                    equals($(this).css('height'), 20);
            });
        });
});
```

Altough this does actually display correctly (the height value of the elements is 20px) the results of the test fail. I assume it's because the scale effect is applied after the test has run. If anyone has any advice to give i'd welcome it.

[image: qunit results]

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the animations before running the test.

```
$("*").stop(false, true);
```

Or you can wait them to finish (described [here](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/09/jquery-waiting-for-multiple-animations-to-complete/))

```
var wait = setInterval(function() {
    if(!$("#testDiv div").is(":animated") ) {
        clearInterval(wait);
        // run tests
    }
}, 100);
```